# Neo4j Php Transaction Create makes duplicates

Tags: neo4j

Im indexing on Neo4j my countries

(Select * from Country) => 3 output (Turkey, Cyprus and England)

and on my php code im creating them on Neo4j

```
 $transaction = $this->neo->beginTransaction();
        foreach(Country::find() as $key => $val)
        {



                    $querya = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query($this->neo, "CREATE (country:Country { pid:".$val->id.",name : '".$val->name."'})");

                    $result = $transaction->addStatements(array($querya));






        }

        $transaction->commit();
```

But on explorer i saw there are 6 index; 2 Turkey, 2.. , 2.. .

Where i'm doing mistake ?

Thanks

Comment: what is the output of Country::find() ?

Comment: if i would fetch names , its output : Turkey, Cyprus and England